# Docker with Rails and Vite: How to run npm dev for Vite

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose, vite

Building a rails api backend with a React front end with Vite for hot module replacement.  Since my M1 Mac can't run anything without failing, I'm using Docker.  I can get the rails server running in Docker without any problems including redis, and the postgres database.  The issue I'm running into is how to start the Vite service.  Vite is installed inside its own client folder where I've also installed npm.  Without Docker, I would normally just open a separate tab in the terminal, cd into the client directory, and then "npm run dev" to start that service.  Not sure how to do that same process in Docker.

Folder structure:

```
--/Project
  --/app (normal rails app folder with Dockerfile)
  --/client (Vite files)
```

Issue I think is just how to setup the docker-compose.yml file and if I'm missing anything in the Dockerfile.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:3.2.2

# Install libvips for Active Storage preview support
RUN apt-get update -qq && \
    apt-get install -y build-essential libvips bash bash-completion libffi-dev tzdata postgresql nodejs npm yarn && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /usr/share/doc /usr/share/man

# Install specific version of Node.js
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs

# Install Yarn
RUN curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add -
RUN echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y yarn

WORKDIR /myapp
COPY . /myapp/

ENV BUNDLE_PATH /gems
RUN bundle install

ENTRYPOINT ["bin/rails"]
CMD ["server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]

EXPOSE 3000
```

docker-compose.yml is below.

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./dbdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"

  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
      - vite
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:password@db:5432/postgres
      - REDIS_URL=redis://redis:6379
    volumes:
      - .:/app

  vite:
    #not sure what to put here

volumes:
  dbdata:
```

I've attempted to add this to the "-vite" section of the docker-compose file, but it fails when I add it:  `"Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "bin/rails": stat bin/rails: no such file or directory: unknown"`

```
vite:
    container_name: vite
    build: ./client
    working_dir: /myapp/client
    volumes:
      - ./client:/myapp/client
    command: "npm run dev"
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
```